# Chassis temperature and Fan status on Cisco 3548 switch

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, cisco-commands, environmental-monitoring

I need to remotely check the status of the fans and temperature of a switch that I currently do not have physical access to. I have done so in the past on a 2950 with the command:

```
Show environment
```

But I don't have this command on this platform. Does anyone know a command I can use check this? I don't have SNMP configured at the moment, I can do if its needed but I would rather just look it up with a command if possible.

The Switch is a WS-C3548-XL running IOS 12.0(5)WC17.

Comment: They don't have any sensors for environmental issues. Only PWR (Pre-PoE) has fan sensors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extend my comment, these switches don't have any pollable environment sensors. Only WS-C3524-PWR-XL-EN model has pollable fan sensor.

They've been completely out of support since 2007 and you'll never get newer software than WC17 which you are running.

We are having difficulties finding people who'll accept them free from us, so we usually just trash them.
If I'd have XL switches and no budget I'd upgrade them to 3550, which is also EOL, but much superior switch and can be acquired for 50USD/pcs. 3550 runs modern IOS, 12.2(55)SE8 but technically is out of SW maintenance.

With 3550 you'd at least get MST, QinQ, L2PT, SSH, proper storm-control, IP routing, QoS, ACLs, SPAN.